# admob sdkを実機で走らすと、エラーになる

Tags: swift, xcode, ios8, swift2

改善策を教えていただけないでしょうか？
エミュレーターでは動きますが、実機はコンパイルエラーになります。

以下参照したホームページです。
https://akira-watson.com/iphone/admob.html
ここに書かれているフレームワークも追加しています。

よろしくお願いいたします。

エラーコードです。

> ld: '/Users/＊＊＊＊＊/Desktop/＊＊＊＊＊/TestKoukoku/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerView.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

テストコードです。

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    // AdMob ID を入れてください
    let AdMobID = "ca-app-pub-59765xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
    let TEST_DEVICE_ID = "61b0154xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe0"
    let AdMobTest:Bool = true
    let SimulatorTest:Bool = true


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var admobView: GADBannerView = GADBannerView()
    admobView = GADBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeBanner)
    admobView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - admobView.frame.height)

    admobView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, admobView.frame.height)
    admobView.adUnitID = AdMobID
    admobView.delegate = self
    admobView.rootViewController = self

    let admobRequest:GADRequest = GADRequest()

    if AdMobTest {
        if SimulatorTest {
            admobRequest.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        }
        else {
            admobRequest.testDevices = [TEST_DEVICE_ID]
        }

    }

    admobView.loadRequest(admobRequest)

    self.view.addSubview(admobView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのエラーメッセージはあなたが自分のアプリに取り込もうとしているフレームワーク(の少なくとも一部)がbitcode対応していないことを示しています。

*You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.*
このエラーメッセージには3つの対応のどれかを行わないといけないと示されています。

- (そのフレームワーク自体を)bitcodeを有効にして再ビルドする
- フレームワークの配布元から(bitcodeに対応した)更新版のライブラリを入手する
- コンパイル中のプロジェクトのターゲットについて、bitcodeを無効化する

最初の2つについては、こちらではどうしようもないので、3番目の設定変更方法を示します。

Project navigatorからPROJECT/TARGETSの設定画面を開いておく。
TARGETSのBuild Settingsのタブを選択する。
(検索窓に「bit」と入力するなどして)Enable Bitcodeの設定箇所を見つける。
※「Build Options」の中にあるはずです。
「Yes」になっているはずなので、そこを「No」に書き換える。

Appleは将来的にApp Storeに提出するアプリに対してbitcode使用を義務化するかもしれません(tvOSでは既に義務化されているようです)が、今の所は無効化しても大丈夫です。

Comment: 義務化の件、将来的には心配ですが、3番目の方法でとりあえず解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「今の所は大丈夫」で根本的な解決を先送りして痛い目にあうというのはよくある話なので、こまめにbitcode対応の更新版が出ていないか(バージョンアップのせいで参考にされた記事通りでは動かなくなってしまう可能性もありますが)確認された方が良いでしょう。サードパーティ製のフレームワークを入れる限り避けられない苦労です。